# regex for optional character with max allowance-python

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to regex and have a problem in hand which I need to develop a pattern in a way that allows for 'A' or 'G' to happen but not both.

I have written this pattern: `r'ACC[A]?[G]?CCG'`

'A and 'G' are optional but I want if 'A' happens, deactivate [G]? and vice versa so they dnt show up after each other.

What would be the best approach to this probelm?

Comment: Can you add examples to the question? The input and output for all relevant combinations helps with answering

Answer (score 1):

To match either A or G but not both, you can use a character class and omit using `?` `{1}` and `|`

```
ACC[AG]CCG
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tFhX4E/1)

The updated code could look be `r'ACC[AG]CCG'`

Answer (score 0):

r'ACC[A|G]?CCG'

A or G matched zero or one times

A good site to test out your regex is https://regex101.com/ which includes a section that explains how it works as well as a quick reference for regex

Comment: thank you, yes, it worked. I also wanted to have at least one of them but not both. So this completed the pattern r'ACC[A|G]{1}?CCG'

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant that you don't want 'A' or 'G' together, not 'A' or 'T', meaning you want your pattern to match either `ACCACCG` or `ACCGCCG` but not `ACCAGCCG`, is that correct?

If so this approach should work:

```py
re.search(r"ACC[A|G]?CCG", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

use an alternative

```
r'ACC(A|G)?CCG'
```

use a character class

```
r'ACC[AG]?CCG'
```

Answer (score -1):

this?

```
if "A" in myString:
  myString.replace("G", "")
```

or this?

```
A = False
G = False

for each in myString:
  if each == "A":
    if not A:
      temp += each
    A = True

  elif each == "G":
    if not G:
      temp += each
    G = True
      
  else:
    temp += each

myString = temp
```